Division property of outer product?
$A = \{a_1,\cdots,a_m\}$ is a multiset consisting of $m$ non-negative real numbers, with at least one element $a_k > 0$.
$B = \{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ and $C = \{c_1,\cdots,c_n\}$ are two multisets each consisting of $n$ non-negative real numbers.
Define $A\otimes B := \{a_ib_j: 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$, and similarly $A\otimes C := \{a_ic_j: 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$.
Now I want to prove that: if $A\otimes B = A\otimes C$, then $B=C$.

I tried to sort (w.l.o.g.) elements in $A$ and make it a vector, and similarly for sorted vectors $B$ and $C$. Elements in $A\otimes B$ and $A\otimes C$ can be arranged into the outer products of vectors. I want to show that with vectors sorted, the index of arrangement is uniquely determined, so as to transform the equality between multisets into equality between matrices.
Update: But the above statement is incorrect when there are negative values (see the example given by @Gerry Myerson where $A=\{1,-1\}$, and $b_j=-c_j$ for all $j$; though there's still isomorphism between $B,C$, as pointed out by @math-physicist).

This is something similar to the division property of equality. One example: if multisets $\{a,b,c,2a,2b,2c\} = \{d,e,f,2d,2e,2f\}$, show that $\{a,b,c\} = \{d,e,f\}$, i.e., the matching must be following ``what it looks should be'', not e.g., $\{a,b,c\}$ matching to $\{a,2a,2b\}$.

What if $A={1,-1}$, and $c_j=b_j$ for all $j$?

@math, I think $\otimes$ has a different meaning at the question you cite.

@math-physicist and @ Gerry Myerson, thanks and I believe it's a same thing; the multiset equality here is the isomorphism $\cong$ between tensors in that post. Though without abstract algebra background, I may need some time to digest that post; or prefer a simple arithmatic proof just for this specific problem.

@Gerry Myerson, "A={1,-1}..", i didnt quite get this question.

I think Gerry Myerson meant $A={\pm 1}$ and $b_j=-c_j$. This is a counterexample to the claim you are trying to prove.

@Alex, right, I meant $c_j=-b_j$. thanks.

Thanks @AlexB. I got it. I know why I can't proceed with sorting vectors when there are negative numbers.
